# ORA-19025 - too many nodes when using extractValue

Tags: xml, oracle

How can i select for the value "USPrice" if PartNumber="926-AA"??

My select always ends in ORA-19025!

```
SELECT extractValue(OBJECT_VALUE, '/PurchaseOrder/Items/Item/USPrice/text()') "PRICE" FROM TMP_TABLE
WHERE extractValue(OBJECT_VALUE,'/PurchaseOrder/Items/Item[@PartNumber]') = '926-AA';
```

Here is the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE TMP_TABLE OF XMLType;
INSERT INTO TMP_TABLE VALUES (XMLType(bfilename('XMLDIR', 'purchaseOrder.xml'),nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));
```

Here is the data:

```
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
  <Address Type="Shipping">
    <Name>Ellen Adams</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
  <Address Type="Billing">
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>USA</Country>
  </Address>
  <DeliveryNotes>Please leave packages in shed by driveway.</DeliveryNotes>
  <Items>
    <Item PartNumber="872-AA">
      <ProductName>Lawnmower</ProductName>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
      <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
    </Item>
    <Item PartNumber="926-AA">
      <ProductName>Baby Monitor</ProductName>
      <Quantity>2</Quantity>
      <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
      <ShipDate>1999-05-21</ShipDate>
    </Item>
  </Items>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you meant to do:

```
select extractvalue(object_value, '/PurchaseOrder/Items/Item[@PartNumber="926-AA"]/USPrice/text()') price
from tmp_table;
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple rows you're running this against, you'd be better off using `XMLTABLE` as `EXTRACTVALUE` has been deprecated since 11gR1:

```
select *
from   tmp_table tt
       cross join xmltable('/PurchaseOrder/Items/Item'
                           passing tt.object_value
                           columns partnumber varchar2(20) path '@PartNumber',
                                   usprice number path 'USPrice') x
where  x.partnumber = '926-AA';
```

Comment: Ok, i have to use the criteria in the xpath syntax instead using it in a where statement with EXTRACTVALUE. Nice. But the code example with XMLTABLE runs in an error ORA-01722 :-(

Comment: When you reference an Oracle error number, could you please put the corresponding error message along with it? Nobody can be expected to remember all the errors and their associated error codes! Also, forcing the people who are trying to help you to waste time looking up something you have at your fingertips is time-consuming and wasteful. (Sorry, pet peeve; you happened to be the straw that broke the camel's back!). Finally, if the usprice node can contain info that isn't a number, then change the datatype in the xmltable column declaration to a varchar2.

Comment: I understand and will promise improvement. Thank you for your helpful answer. Now everthing works fine.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to sort things out *{:-D